# No sound in the output track when i'm writing into .wav file

Tags: c++, audio, wav

I'm quite new in C++ and i'm trying to parse .wav file in order to add some audioeffects on it then. So, at first I'm trying to read and parse input .wav file and then write it into output .wav file. The output file has same size in explorer and some duration in audioplayer, but the sound is absent when it's playing. What's wrong with it?

Here my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct WavHeader
{
    char                chunkId[4];     // RIFF, FMT, DATA, e.t.c.
    unsigned long       ChunkSize;      // Chunk Size  
};

struct RiffHeader : WavHeader
{
    char                format[4];      // WAVE Header      
};

struct FmtHeader : WavHeader
{                            
    unsigned short      AudioFormat;    // Audio format 1=PCM,6=mulaw,7=alaw, 257=IBM Mu-Law, 258=IBM A-Law, 259=ADPCM 
    unsigned short      NumOfChan;      // Number of channels 1=Mono 2=Sterio                   
    unsigned long       SamplesPerSec;  // Sampling Frequency in Hz                             
    unsigned long       bytesPerSec;    // bytes per second 
    unsigned short      blockAlign;     // 2=16-bit mono, 4=16-bit stereo 
    unsigned short      bitsPerSample;  // Number of bits per sample
};

struct DataHeader : WavHeader
{
};

struct Wav
{
    RiffHeader RiffHeader;
    FmtHeader FmtHeader;
    DataHeader DataHeader;
    vector<char> Data;
};

/// <summary>
/// Read/write .wav files.
/// </summary>
class WavFileManager
{
public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Read whole .wav file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Path to file.</param>
    Wav ReadAll(const string& path)
    {
        ifstream file(path);

        if (!file)
        {
            throw runtime_error("Can't open file: " + path);
        }

        Wav* wavFile = new Wav();

        wavFile->RiffHeader = ReadHeader<RiffHeader>(file);

        if (wavFile->RiffHeader.format != "WAVE\0")
        {
            // throw runtime_error("Wrong format. File: " + path);
        }

        wavFile->FmtHeader = ReadHeader<FmtHeader>(file);

        if (!TrySkipChunksBefore(file, "data"))
        {
            throw runtime_error("Can't find wav data. File: " + path);
        }

        wavFile->DataHeader = ReadHeader<DataHeader>(file);


        vector<char>& data = wavFile->Data;
        data.reserve(wavFile->DataHeader.ChunkSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < wavFile->DataHeader.ChunkSize; i++)
        {
            char buffer;
            file.read((char*)&buffer, sizeof(char));
            data.push_back(buffer);
        }
        reverse(data.begin(), data.end());


        file.close();
        return *wavFile;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read header of .wav file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">File stream.</param>
    /// <returns>Header of type T.</returns>
    template<typename T>
    T ReadHeader(ifstream& file)
    {
        T header;
        int headerSize = sizeof(T);
        file.read((char*)&header, headerSize);
        return header;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read data chunk of .wav file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">File stream.</param>
    /// <param name="size">Chunk size.</param>
    /// <returns>Array of bytes.</returns>
    char* ReadChunk(ifstream& file, unsigned long size)
    {
        char* chunk = new char[size];
        file.read(chunk, size);
        return chunk;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if .wav header has following chunkId.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="header">.wav header.</param>
    /// <param name="chunkId">Id to compare.</param>
    bool HasChunkID(const WavHeader& header, const char chunkId[4])
    {
        return ((header.chunkId[0] == chunkId[0]) &&
            (header.chunkId[1] == chunkId[1]) &&
            (header.chunkId[2] == chunkId[2]) &&
            (header.chunkId[3] == chunkId[3]));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Skip all chunks before reqired chunk.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">File stream.</param>
    /// <param name="chunkId">Id of required chunk.</param>
    bool TrySkipChunksBefore(ifstream& file, const char chunkId[4])
    {
        while (!file.eof())
        {
            streampos pos = file.tellg();
            WavHeader header = ReadHeader<WavHeader>(file);
            char* chunk = ReadChunk(file, header.ChunkSize);
            if (HasChunkID(header, chunkId))
            {
                file.clear();
                file.seekg(pos);
                return true;
            }
            delete[] chunk;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write all data into file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">Wav to write.</param>
    /// <param name="path">Path to output file.</param>
    void WriteAll(Wav data, const string& path)
    {
        ofstream file(path, ios::binary);
        file.write((char*)&data.RiffHeader, sizeof(RiffHeader));
        file.write((char*)&data.FmtHeader, sizeof(FmtHeader));
        file.write((char*)&data.DataHeader, sizeof(DataHeader));
        reverse(data.Data.begin(), data.Data.end());
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Data.size(); i++)
        {
            file.write((char*)&data.Data[i], sizeof(char));
        }
        file.close();
    }
};

int main()
try
{
    auto* mgr = new WavFileManager();
    auto wav = mgr->ReadAll ("input.wav");
    mgr->WriteAll(wav, "output.wav");
}
catch (runtime_error& e)
{
    cerr << "Error! " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `reserve` on the data vector twice? in `ReadAll(..)` around the `for` loop

Comment: First one is reSERVE(), second one is reVERSE(). They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved were easy.

```
ifstream file(path, ios::binary);
```

instead of

```
ifstream file(path);
```